# jQuery - Validation plugin submitting form in error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im using the a jQuery validation plugin ... and trying to post the data using ajax.

The problem im finding is that once the ajax runs, it submits the default 'action' in the form tag.

The jQuery code i have is as follows, im hoping someone can help me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            var platinumForm = jQuery('#platinum-form');

            platinumForm.validate({
                rules: {
                    fullname: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    fullname: "Please enter your Fullname",
                    email: "Please enter a valid Email Address"
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.prev() );
                },
                submitHandler: function() {
                    jQuery('#platinum-form').fadeOut();

                    var iName = platinumForm.find('#fullname');

                    var data = 'fullname=' + iName.val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/my-processing-page.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        dataType: "html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            console.log(html);
                            if (html.indexOf('Sorry') > -1) {
                                $('#paymentMessage').html(html).fadeIn('slow');
                            } else {
                                $('#form-payment-content').slideUp('slow', function(){
                                    $('#thankyouMessage .message').html(html).parent().fadeIn('slow');

                                });
                            }
                        }

                    });                     

                },
            })              
        });
    </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Try adding `return false;` to your submit handler.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Write `return false;` after `$.ajax`

```
               .......
               $.ajax({
                    url: "/my-processing-page.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "html",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        console.log(html);
                        if (html.indexOf('Sorry') > -1) {
                            $('#paymentMessage').html(html).fadeIn('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#form-payment-content').slideUp('slow', function(){
                                $('#thankyouMessage .message').html(html).parent().fadeIn('slow');

                            });
                        }
                    }

                });   
                return false;
                ......
```

Comment: This doesnt work ... When, i change $.ajax to jQuery.ajax it doesnt submit the form like i want, but then the ajax doesnt work properly